# How do i create a scroll to top button on a single page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After some decent search time, i still haven't found any information for this specific function but i'm sure it can be done.

The site i'm working with has very short pages albeit one. I created a scroll to top button for this single long page with no problems. I want this button to only work for this individual page but when i load another page on the site i get console errors - 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at scrollFunction'

This is the function i've attempted to use to check the href of the page:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("portfolio.html")) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("scrollButton").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("scrollButton").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the answer proposed by Sujen K., but has some differences that simplify code clarity and makes things a bit better for performance:

```js
var elementExists =  document.getElementById('scrollButton');
// We can skip the page URL check because in theory this
// behavior is desired on any page with the scrollButton
if (elementExists) {
// By moving the onScroll function into the if statement
// it no longer has to check on pages without scrollButton
// We can also simplify how it is set up.
    window.onscroll = function () {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
            // We can reuse elementExists here for a minor
            // performance gain instead of having to get it again.
            elementExists.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            elementExists.style.display = "none";
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This works and seems more functionally directed at what i'm trying to achieve. Please excuse my lack of storing scrollButton in a variable, i am still semi new to javascript and although it slows me down, i understand it better when i write it out. I do go back and create variables as soon as i know the script works.

Comment: No worries -- I just figured I would show how I would do this and comment on each part. Even if it doesn't help you personally, someone else could stumble along and find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, your statement will be always considered as true, because of `indexOf` ([see spec](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)) return the index (number) of the first founded occurrence, otherwise will return `-1`.

You should update your code in way:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("portfolio.html") !== -1) {
```

Comment: Thank you. It completely flew over my head that -1 will return if there is never an occurrence found.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/neeklamy/RpPEe/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('.scrollup').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Also - consider ditching JS and just give your body an ID (id="something"), then have a link point at (href="#something"). It solves the problem with no scripting at all.

Answer (score 0):

Look this solution: 
https://jsfiddle.net/9x204t2o/1/

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                  $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
            } else {
                  $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
            }
    });

    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
            return false;
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.scrollToTop{
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: whiteSmoke;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_up_alt1-512.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 40px;
    background-position: 40px 30px;
}
.scrollToTop:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="scrollToTop">Scroll To Top</a>
[...]
```

Can help?